# Android published app has too many screenshots

Tags: google-play, screenshot

My app in Google Play has 10 screenshots when I only uploaded 5. In the developer console there are only 5. I tried deleting all of them and uploading just 5, but it is still showing 10 in the store. Has anyone else had this problem or know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that if you upload 5 screenshots, one for the phone, 7 tablet, 10 inch tablet, it will display all of them, on all devices and on website. So you have to just upload 5. I just put 2 in every device screenshot area.

Answer (score 3):

Changes to your app listing take several hours to propagate through all of Google's servers.  Give it some time.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is made for tablets too, then just upload those images. The play store will show those on phones too.